# How can I measure how long Entity Framework takes to compile a query?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework to perform some rather complex queries against my database.  I know the first time EF runs a query, it needs to compile the query before executing.  I'd like to measure how long this takes.  I am using MiniProfiler elsewhere, and I'm hoping there is just a method somewhere that I can override and wrap with a timer.  Best case scenario, some sort of EF class has a `CompileQuery` method I can override.

Does something like this exist or is there another way for me to measure how long it takes for Entity Framework to compile a query?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `ToString()`, it will convert the `IQueryable` into SQL statement.

```
var watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
query.ToString();
watch.Stop();
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have dozens and dozens of these statements that I want to monitor in a production application, so doing this means a little extra processing (eg. turn it into a query once to time it, and then again to be executed).  Is there some way I can, say, turn it into a SQL query and then pass the result into another method to be executed?

Comment: @user2719100, have you tried using [compiled query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx)?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to make a decision about.  Is it worth it to turn all of my queries into compiled queries, and if so, which ones are my priority.  From what I understand from the article you linked, however, since I am using .NET 4.5 I'm already getting the benefit of cached queries, so I'm not sure how much faster a compiled query will be.  Also, compiled queries don't seem to help with app warmup time, which is where I'm seeing the most slowness (eg. the first time a query is executed)